# Bleed From Shackles

Tags: ellipsis, causatives

For this:

> [link](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2682388/Incredible-sight-elephant-cried-Raju-held-chains-beaten-abused-fifty-years-day-released-tears-rolled-face.html)
>   Raju the elephant was left ***bleeding from spiked shackles*** and living on hand-outs from passing tourists after he was captured and tied up by his ‘owner’.

Is "bleeding from spiked shackles", because the blood could come from a wound, but not from shackles?

Comment: Actually, this would be more accurately expressed as "Raju was bleeding from wounds inflicted by spiked shackles"; but the Mail cultivates a conversational style which obeys the Tolerance Maxim: *Whatever should be understood can be omitted*.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, "from" is used in accordance  with this [definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/from):

> used as a function word to indicate the source, cause, agent, or basis

So the shackles are the cause of the bleeding, not what bleeds.

Comment: Suppose I was cut by a knife and now I'm bleeding.  Could I write "I am bleeding ***from*** the knife"?

Comment: @meatie Yes, but I can't tell how natural it would sound. But things like: "die from a gun" sound right to me.